# TFS - Make 2 Existing Folders related branches

Tags: tfs, branch, branching-and-merging, tfvc

I am working with TFS 2012 and wondering if I can accomplish something easily.  I have two folders with several sub folders ... in a previous SC they were branches of each other.

Is there a way in TFS to make them have a "relationship"?  I've used the "Convert to Branch" on both.  When I try to "Merge", not surprisingly it has an "!" mark and says "A merge relationship does not exist between the source and the target.  A baseless merge will be performed."

So is there any way to "create" that relationship? I realize I could delete one of the folders in TFS, create the branch, and then copy all the original files into the branch location and then check them in. But outside of that is there a way?  I tried "Reparent" but the pick list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to go to the commandline where you can perform a baseless merge using:

```
Tf vc merge $/proj/branch1 $/proj/branch2 /baseless /recursive
```

After which you can use the reparent feature to setup the correct parent/child relation.

See also

- https://alistairbmackay.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/tfs-reparenting-a-branch/

Comment: I will try this on Monday.

Comment: To do a baseless merge **without updating the child branch**, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56902384/429973